# ArcGIS historical traffic data with Impedance attribute of miles

Tags: arcgis-server, network-analyst, arcgis-10.3, routing, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to solve a route using an impedance of miles (to get the shortest route) through ArcGIS Sever 10.3.1 rest API.

However, I would also like to get the travel time of this route based on historical traffic data for a specific date/time. It seems like ArcGIS only supports historical traffic data if the impedance is TravelTime.

The message returned by the server is:

```
type: 50,
description: "The start time was ignored because the impedance attribute is not time-based."
```

Is it even possible to use traffic data on non time-based routes?

**EDIT:**

I did manage to find this in some [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Route_service_with_synchronous_execution/02r300000036000000/):

> To use traffic in the analysis, set impedanceAttributeName to TravelTime, and assign a value to startTime...
>   ...Traffic is supported only with the driving time impedance or travel mode.

Which seems to indicate this isn't possible, but that surprises me. I would have thought this was not an uncommon request. Does anyone know of a workaround or alternative method?

Comment: I believe in the network analyst options you can set your impedance to time based.

Comment: @user3338197 Yes, you can. But I want the route optimized to be the shortest distance, therefore the impedance needs to be miles.

Comment: Hmm I will have to do some research on this one,  I think it should be possible to do what you want

Comment: How should the router recognize traffic delay if you want just the shortest path? Or do you want the distance for the fastest path?

Comment: @Karussell I want travel time (with traffic) for the shortest path.The data should be there because the route is just a series of edges, and edges have cost attributes. So each edge should have traffic cost data associated with it regardless of how the route was optimized (unless I'm misunderstanding how routes work, which is quite possible. I'm a software engineer, not a GIS analyst). It seems that getting that traffic data outside of a time-based route isn't possible, though.

Comment: Ok, understood and should be possible indeed. And sorry can't help you here as I'm no arcgis user, but as you are a software engineer you can have a look at the open source routing engine GraphHopper (note: I'm the author)